# Singleton Class throws System.TypeInitializationException

Tags: c#, singleton

I'm new to C# and I'm unsure why this singleton pattern is throwing a System.TypeIntializationException:

Here is the ViewModel setting a reference to the ProductRepository singleton:

```
private void BindingChartView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Call the method that creates a DataSet
    ProductRepository taskRepo = this.SetupData();
}
```

Here is how the ProductRepository singleton is defined:

```
namespace Chart.Model
{
   public class ProductRepository
   {
      private static readonly ProductRepository instance;
      public static ProductRepository Instance
      {
         get { return instance; }
      }
      static ProductRepository()
      {
         instance = new ProductRepository();
      }

      private ProductRepository()
      {
         InitializeRepos();
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT: Here is what I have for the Setup() method.  InitializeRepos() is all commented out.

```
    private ProductRepository SetupData()
    {

        taskRepo = ProductRepository.Instance;
        return taskRepo;              
    }
```

Basically, a watch on taskRepo is what is showing me the exception, and it says that it was thrown by Chart.Model.ProductRepository.Instance.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information to go off of. The problem is going either be in `SetupData()` or `InitializeRepos()`. Please post those methods and stack trace.

Comment: please show InitializeRepos() method and setupdata().

Comment: Original post edited above.

Answer (score 1):

I apologize, I found that the problem was a reference to a 3rd party dll's class in the private constructor, just after InitializeRepos().  I had parsed it out here to simplify, but it turned out to be the culprit.